# Bottom part of tab bar does not get properly colored

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

I want to custom color my tab bar element in my custom UITabController sub-class and it works fine when I'm doing it with: 
`tabBar.barTintColor = .blue` (With any system or custom color)

But when I'm trying to add a gradient using my custom UIImage extension

```
extension UIImage {
    static func gradientImageWithBounds(bounds: CGRect, colors: [CGColor]) -> UIImage {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = colors
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.masksToBounds = true

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
        gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}

tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage.gradientImageWithBounds(bounds: tabBar.bounds, colors: [Colors.tabBarTopGradient, Colors.tabBarBottomGradient]))
```

I having trouble with gradient not getting properly applied to the bottom part of the tab bar around the phone's safe area. What am I missing here? It looks like that: [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try setting the gradient tint in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you create the gradient based on tab bar height, what you need is to add the additional height to the tab bar height

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var frame = tabBar.bounds
    let safeAreaHeight = safeAreaInsets.bottom
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height + safeAreaHeight

    tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage.gradientImageWithBounds(bounds: frame, colors: [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]))
}

public var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
    guard let window: UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first else {
        return .zero
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *),
        UIWindow.instancesRespond(to: #selector(getter: window.safeAreaInsets)) {
        return window.safeAreaInsets
    }

    return .zero
}
```